# Implementing Achievements in iOS App without Game Center

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Is there anyway possible to implement challenges and achievements in an app without using Game Center. The current app that I'm working on is not a game, but has challenges and achievements based on photo users submit. For example if a user uploads a photo of their pet, they get 50 points for  submitting that picture.

Comment: Are you looking to save the achievements/challenges locally on the user's device?

Comment: @RMK-Jacob No I don't plan on saving the challenges locally on the user's device.

Comment: I posted an answer to your question below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use that, I create a simple class for iOS game center in GitHub
https://github.com/DaRkD0G/Easy-Game-Center-Swift

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend having an if statement (or something like that) set up, and whenever the user "completes" the achievement, it changes a value on your server to "completed", and adds the number of points earned from the achievement to the user's overall points. If you already have a database storing user account data, you could add fields for the achievements. Then when the app loads the "achievements" page, you could just check the server real quick and display the results.